# Replacement Refrigator Fan Evaporator Motor with same DC measurements as original but bigger, is it safe to install?

Tags: refrigerator, fans, electric-motor, evaporative-cooling, freezer

I am doing a DIY on my LG refrigerator. My freezer/refrigator fan evaporator motor gave out. I ordered the part but the parts place sent me the wrong motor twice. It is different from the original part but they claim it is for that model ( I can only assume that maybe this is the aftermarket replacement). It has the same amps and voltage DC but is bigger and has different numbers on the case that I am not sure what represent. Can't get a resolution or answer to my question from them and I have zero knowledge on this stuff so I am coming here to check if it would be compatible/safe because the new motor technically fits.

I'm not really sure if this is a big deal in the first place, I can't image anything going wrong but I also don't want to be further damage my refrigerator.

My LG refrigerator model is lrfws2906d

Here is the original motor(smaller and different numbers on the case, 6 and 8)
[image]

[image]

The new motor that came in has these markings(L7-4,R7-3)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually if it has the same voltage and amps and fits the mounting it should work.  Most of the rest is difference in efficiently and quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it FIT? The replacement might, just might, be a part re-engineered to not fail like the original, smaller one did. If it fits in the fridge, that seems quite likely.

Comment: I don't even see any mounting provisions on the new motor...at least the old guy has mounting ears with holes.

Comment: Quite possibly the holes were not used, since the replacement has ears, but no holes. It may snap in place into a bracket or some-such.

Comment: yes it fits perfectly and the ears were not used

Answer (score 1):

If it fits in the space available, has compatible mounting, shaft dimensions, and has the same electrical (volts & amps) and mechanical (speed & direction) characteristics, then I don't see why you couldn't use it